# HTML5 Canvas and manipulating

Tags: jquery, html, canvas

I havent had much exposure to the `Canvas` element in HTML5. I have done basic things such as rendering a rectangle to the `Canvas`

It it possible to assign a `Class` or `Id` to said rectangle and manipulate via `jQuery` such as assigning a click event?

Comment: Why not make your life easier by using a wrapper such as Raphael? (http://raphaeljs.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question: No, it's not possible: elements, shapes and images drawn on `<canvas>` elements are not part of the DOM.

Yet, there are a lot of "framework"-type of libraries out there that add interactive capabilities. As mentioned in the comments there's **[Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com)** or **[jCanvas](http://calebevans.me/projects/jcanvas/index.php)** or **[Kinetic](http://www.kineticjs.com/)** or many many more.

If you want to go canvas on your own I found the tutorials on **[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial)** or **[html5rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/)** pretty useful.